# Numeric custom filter with ransacker is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, ransack, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I am trying to make a new custom filter in ActiveAdmin of a rails application. When I put bellow code

`filter :premium_scenes_in`

it displays a input field as text input field (with option "contains", "equals" and etc) but I want an input field as numeric with option "equals", "greater than" or "less than".

I tried to use:

`filter :premium_scenes_in, as: :numeric`
or 
`filter :premium_scenes_in, as: :numeric_range`

But each time it shows an error `Unable to find input class NumaricRangeInput`

This is my code in model

```
ransacker :premium_scenes,
  formatter: proc { |number|
    results = Tour.all.map{|tour| tour if tour.scenes.count > number}
    results = results.present? ? results : nil
   }, splat_params: true do |parent|
  parent.table[:id]
end
```

Comment: Note: I have very little experience with what you're trying to do so can't give specific help... BUT I notice what could be a typo here: `NumaricRangeInput` and just thought I should point it out in case it's a typo in your code (eg you've declared `as: :numaric_range` accidentally or something), and not just the question... worth double-checking for all the tiny things.

Comment: I did not get you. What should I use instead of numaric_range ?

Comment: The error says Num-a-ricRangeInput, not Num-e-ricRangeInput as one might expect.

Comment: I see what you meant. Yeah, I changed that. It was a type but still it does not solve my problem. Now it is showing `undefined method 'premium_scenes_in_equals' for Ransack::Search<class: Tour, base: Grouping <combinator: and>>:Ransack::Search`

Comment: That sounds like a new and separate bug... I'd start by searching your project for `premium_scenes_in_equals` to see where it's trying to call that.

Comment: did you check this? [Problem with custom numeric filter](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/3683#issuecomment-149626599)

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant `as: :number`. The supported input types are documented in the [Formtastic README here](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic#the-available-inputs)

Comment: I have used `number` and now It is showing `undefined method 'premium_scenes_in' for Ransack::Search<class: Tour, base: Grouping <combinator: and>>:Ransack::Search
Did you mean?  presence_in`